# Uploading file in Rails gives String filename instead of File or StringIO object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file-upload

Rails 3, JRuby 1.6.7.2

I've been trying something "elementary", just uploading a single text file via a form for processing in my app.  The problem I'm seeing is that instead of a StringIO or File, I'm getting just a string of the file name.

Here's the form code

```
= form_tag(:controller => "api/#{CURRENT_API_VERSION}/api", :action => 'file', :method=> :post, :multipart => true) do
    = label_tag "file"
    = file_field_tag "upload[file]"
    = submit_tag 'Analyze!'
```

And the controller code that is just giving me @upload as a string containing the file name.

```
def file
        @upload = params[:upload][:file]
        render :template => 'api/file.html.haml'
      end
```

Running debugger in the controller gives me @upload.class = String, and it doesn't respond to any file or StringIO methods, such as read.

Answer (score 22):

Found the answer here.  It turns out I was just screwing up the form_tag method call.  You need to separate the options that are meant for "url_for" and the other options, specifically the multi-part option.

So the correct code for the form is:

```
= form_tag({:controller => "api/#{CURRENT_API_VERSION}/api", :action => 'file', :method=> :post}, {:multipart => true}) do
    = label_tag "file"
    = file_field_tag "upload[file]"
    = submit_tag 'Analyze!'
```

Thanks to Rob Biedenharn for answering this five years ago on ruby-forum!
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125637

Comment: Same as `form_tag({:controller => "api/#{CURRENT_API_VERSION}/api", :action => 'file', :method=> :post}, :multipart => true)`